# $O$ is the center of the circle, $AC$..

Tags: geometry

In the given figure,  $O$ is the center of the circle,  $AC$ is the chord and $BT=TC$. Prove that $\angle OAT=\angle OBT$.
[image]

My Attempt 
If we join $BC$ then we have, 
$\angle TBC=\angle TCB$  {Given that $BT=TC$}.
And,
$\angle AOB=2\angle TCB=2\angle TBC$    {By the relation that central angle is double of inscribed angle standing on same arc and from above}.

I got struck at here. Please help me to complete this.

Comment: Instead of joining $BC$, I'd look at adding the line segment $OC$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Delta OTB$ is congruent to $\Delta OTC$ so $\angle OBT =\angle OCT = \angle OAT$ since $\Delta OAC$ is isosceles.